# how to make the rotation in clockwise direction

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

i have created a  wheel and added the rotation now its rotating in the anticlockwise direction,how can it made to be rotated in the clockwise direction

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour {



public List<int> prize;
public List<AnimationCurve> animationCurves;

private bool spinning;    
private float anglePerItem;    
private int randomTime;
private int itemNumber;

void Start(){
    spinning = false;
    anglePerItem = 360/prize.Count;        
}

void  Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !spinning) {

        randomTime = Random.Range (5, 10);
        itemNumber = Random.Range (0, prize.Count);
        float maxAngle = 360 * randomTime + (itemNumber * anglePerItem);

        StartCoroutine (SpinTheWheel (1 * randomTime, maxAngle));
    }
}

IEnumerator SpinTheWheel (float time, float maxAngle)
{
    spinning = true;

    float timer = 0.0f;        
    float startAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;        
    maxAngle = maxAngle - startAngle;

    int animationCurveNumber = Random.Range (0, animationCurves.Count);
    Debug.Log ("Animation Curve No. : " + animationCurveNumber);

    while (timer < time) {
        //to calculate rotation
        float angle = maxAngle * animationCurves [animationCurveNumber].Evaluate (timer / time) ;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, angle + startAngle);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return 0;
    }

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, maxAngle + startAngle);
    spinning = false;

    Debug.Log ("Prize: " + prize [itemNumber]);//use prize[itemNumnber] as per requirement
}    
}
```

also now it starts rotates and after the time finish it suddenly stops, how can it be made like ,it stops like decreasing the speed

Answer (score 0):

I guess a very simple solution to your problem would be to replace:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, angle + startAngle);
```

with:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, -(angle + startAngle));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, angle + startAngle);
```

At:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, startAngle - angle);
```